# Link Tracking with DTM and Custom Variables

Tags: javascript, analytics, adobe-analytics

I need to capture the link that was clicked as well as the page that the link was clicked on using Adobe DTM, and then pass it into an evar and sprop. I don't need pageviews, so the s.tl() is used.

I'm using an event based rule with "click" as my event type, with my element tag/selector as "a" for the anchor tag.

Below is the page code that I'm using in DTM - but my problem is, I'm getting an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL (line: 1, col:3)" and I can't seem to figure out why.

Ultimately - is this the right approach to take, or is there a more simplified approach or better solution?

```
// Custom Link Tracking
$(“a”).click(function(event) {
console.log($(this).text();
s.eVarXX = $(this).text();
```

Comment: Where did you take `addEvent` function? It has a syntax error: `d=’,’`

Comment: Cleaned up the code, since all I really need is the evar or sprop. Does that help, Artyom?

Comment: Well, the error suggests, that the token at position 1:3 is invalid. `“` should be `"`, I believe.

Comment: at face value, the immediate problem is the code you posted has smart-quotes around the `a` selector. smart-quotes is not valid javascript syntax. Use straight single or double quotes. But @MarkStringham makes a deeper point in his answer below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41743785/3640277
please tell me the answer for the quetion in above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using an event-based rule that already listens for the anchor click you don't need another jQuery function.

You can simply grab both the href and link text within the Adobe Analytics section of your rule:

```
s.prop1 = $(this).text() // link text
s.eVar1 = $(this).attr("href") // Link URL
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks @Mark - can you clarify for me your last sentence? Am I adding the syntax to the AA Global Variables & Events section, under eVars/Props? Or am I adding it using the AA Custom Page Code section?

Comment: You should set these vars within the AA section of your event-based rule that captures the link click (not the UI of the rule). I should also mention that this code also assumes that jQuery is loaded on the page.

Comment: you can also use `%this.innerText%` and `%this.href%` in the "wizard" fields.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Agreed.Your approach will work just as well.